# GMF display diagram example

Tags: eclipse, uml, eclipse-emf, eclipse-emf-ecore, eclipse-gmf

How can I display a GMF diagram, with the file format "*.ecorediag" in Eclipse in a View? 
The diagram should not be editable.

Is there a simple sample view that loads a diagram from say "/home/diagrams/test.ecorediag"

Comment: eclipse provides a built-in editor for .ecore-diag files.  Just select the .ecore-diag file, right click, edit. However it's an _editor_ not a viewer.  Must it be read-only?  If so, what happens if you set the file permissions on the .ecore-diag file to read-only?

Comment: I know about the built in editor. But I am trying to make a new Eclipse plugin. I need to have the ability to customize the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GMF diagrams (including ecorediag) are rendered on the editor with the help of "org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.parts.DiagramGraphicalViewer".

So the bare minimum code to make this work

```
DiagramGraphicalViewer viewer = new DiagramGraphicalViewer();
viewer.createControl(composite);

RootEditPart root = EditPartService.getInstance().createRootEditPart(
                diagram);
viewer.setRootEditPart(root);
viewer.setEditPartFactory(new EcoreEditPartProvider());

viewer.getControl().setBackground(ColorConstants.listBackground);

viewer.setContents(diagram);
```