# Use eclipse GMF to create read only diagram

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-gmf

I followed the file system example http://gmfsamples.tuxfamily.org/wiki/doku.php?id=gmf_tutorial1

what I wanted to do is not using the generated editor with its palette.

I created a new plugin with one view and I wanted to create a diagram programatically inside this view to show for instance 2 objects connected with link

I came across this answer [GMF display diagram example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148243/gmf-display-diagram-example)

but it didn't help me a lot.

in createPartControl of my view I did

```
@Override
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    DiagramGraphicalViewer viewer = new DiagramGraphicalViewer();
    viewer.createControl(parent);

    RootEditPart root = EditPartService.getInstance().createRootEditPart(diagram);
    viewer.setRootEditPart(root);
    viewer.setEditPartFactory(new EcoreEditPartProvider());

    viewer.getControl().setBackground(ColorConstants.listBackground);

    viewer.setContents(diagram);

}
```

as in the answer but I didn't know how to get that "diagram" variable

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be use the same GraphicalViewer for your view and the same diagram as well. Just get your `DiagramEditPart` from the viewer and call `disableEditMode()` on it. (Do the appropriate type casting if necessary).